# Fixed background image on div not working on iOS device? [JSFiddle inside]

Tags: html, css

Here is the basic layout of what I'm doing: a bunch of divs stacked on top of each other (all 100% width) with some divs containing fixed background images. They render great on desktop browsers but do not work on iOS devices (the background images scroll and they don't fill the screen properly).

How do I get this working on iOS?

https://jsfiddle.net/8hfa679n/

```
#about {
    background-image:url("http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2016/06/10/4k-desktop-wallpaper_065227602_309.jpg");
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info: iOS version, browser version, example picture, etc...
have you tried [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp)?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a media query with Javascript and pull up the css according to the device being used,

You will just have a add the following code to your css :

```
background-attachment:scroll
```

To pull up a different css for a particular browser use this :

```
if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) 
{
   document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" href="../component/newstyle.css" />');
```

Let me know if this works out :)